# suppress stars and notes from stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer

How can I remove the stars and notes from a regression table output using stargazer?

I tried including:

```
star.cutoffs = NA
```

It removed the stars, however, at the end of the table it appears "Note: NA" which I would like also to remove.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to remove the note section you can add the argument `omit.table.layout = "n"`

You can see this cheatsheet : http://jakeruss.com/cheatsheets/stargazer.html
and [this section](http://jakeruss.com/cheatsheets/stargazer.html#omit-whole-parts-of-the-table) inside it.

After loading stargazer, have also a look at `?"table layout characters"` for a full list of codes to be used within the `omit.table.layout` argument.